# C++ CryptDecrypt error NTE_BAD_DATA

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, encryption, windows-console

I am able to decrypt a small text file with "This is a plaintext" in it after encrypting it. However when I try to decrypt a larger file size, I end up with an error of **NTE_BAD_DATA**.

Anyone could point out what could possibly go wrong?

Below is a extracted portion of the whole code.

```
#define ENCRYPT_BLOCK_SIZE 256

dwBlockLen = 1000 - 1000 % ENCRYPT_BLOCK_SIZE;
dwBufferLen = dwBlockLen;

if (!ReadFile(hSourceFile, pbBuffer, dwBlockLen, &dwCount, NULL)) {
    handleError("Error reading from source file.\n", GetLastError());
    goto Exit_decryptFile;
}

if (dwCount <= dwBlockLen) {
    fEOF = TRUE;
}

if (!CryptDecrypt(hKey, 0, fEOF, 0, pbBuffer, &dwCount)) {
    handleError("Error during CryptDecrypt.\n", GetLastError());
    goto Exit_decryptFile;
}
```

Comment: You are calling `GetLastError` potentially too late. You will want to call it **immediately** after the condition has been established, where it returns a meaningful value.

Comment: @IInspectable I did call GetLastError after every API. The program only fail at CryptDecrypt. Do you need me to upload the whole code here for you to take a look?

Comment: The order of evaluation of function arguments is unspecified. We don't know the `handleError` function signature, and for all we know, it could construct some temporary from the string literal (e.g. a `std::string`), thereby invalidating the result of `GetLastError`. Don't have us guess, produce a [mcve].

Comment: @IInspectable i have uploaded the header and the implementer on pastebin. Do take a look. header: https://pastebin.com/5KU21KFC        implementer: https://pastebin.com/sTH5C6PK

Comment: **All** code must be **in the question**. For good reasons. There is virtue in producing a good question. See [ask] for guidance.

Comment: @IInspectable I am unable to put the codes in the question as the codes are too long. Thanks for enlightening me on this! Now im slowly learning what are the rules in forum :)

Comment: You aren't asked to put *"the code"* into the question. You are required to produce a [mcve]. People usually grasp the concept *"complete"* without much trouble. *"Minimal"*, on the other hand, is rarely understood, or simply ignored. Probably because that requires *real* work. Anyway, Stack Overflow is not a forum. It's a Q&A site with different rules and different goals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because You read 232 bytes. If text is small (less 232 bytes), then You decrypt one (final) block. If text is big enough - You decrypt block and buffer's size should be a multiple of the block size.

Comment: Sorry to ask, but how should i change my code? I printed out dwCount to be 896

Comment: but how do i specify the bytes to read and the buffer size? The code that i used are referenced from microsoft website but they use RSA instead.

Comment: Your condition is wrong: 
if (dwCount <= dwBlockLen) {
            fEOF = TRUE;
        }
If text is bigger then 768, You read and try to decrypt only first portion...

Comment: Yes you are right! I should have set to (dwCount < dwBlockLen) { fEOF = TRUE; }. I recalculated the whole block again and find this problem. Thanks so much for helping me out. Appreciated much!